# How can I get back 10.11 El Capitan after a re-install gave me 10.7 Lion?

Tags: macos

I have an old 2011 MacBook Air. I had 10.11 El Capitan, but when I wiped my hard disk and re-installed the OS, it went back to 10.7.5 Lion.

Is it possible to get back to El Capitan?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886

Comment: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single post. I've changed the original title _"How do I find out the latest Mac OS I can upgrade to?"_ as the first answer that was posted handled your second question. If you cannot find the answer to the previous title's question, then please post that as a separate one.

Answer (score 1):

**Referencing:** https://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-downgrade-to-an-earlier-version-of-macos/

If you have a Time Machine backup (an OS stored usually on an external drive), then you can revert to it the following way.

**- (If you do this, make sure to save all the changes to documents and such, on a drive or something.):**

- "If the backup is stored on an external or network drive, then make sure this drive is available to your Mac.
- Restart your Mac while holding down the ‘Command+R’ keys. Release these keys as soon as you see the Apple logo.
- In macOS Utilities, select ‘Restore from Time Machine Backup.’
- Click ‘Continue.’
- On the ‘Restore from Time Machine’ screen, click ‘Continue.’
- Select your restore source.
- The next screen will display all of your backups. Choose the backup that you want to reinstate, which will typically be the last backup you created before updating macOS.
- Your Mac will now restore this backup, and downgrade you to an earlier version of macOS in the process!"

If you don't have the OS saved:

- "You'll need to create a bootstable installer."
- You need a flash-drive with at leat 12 gb available.
- If the OS is on the App store, you should be able to re-download it".
- "Launch the App Store"
- Click "Purchases tab".
- Find the version you want, and click install (to the flashdrive, I suppose)

If you can't find the version that you want, from the App store (like version ***Snow Leopard***, which wasn't on the App store, this would require buying a CD or DVD that has it):

**Don't download from a third party source because of the risk of viruses.**

- Follow the steps in the [referenced article](https://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-downgrade-to-an-earlier-version-of-macos/) (it's about 3/4 of the way down the page).